# Motor stall detector with a voltage divider in parallel to the motor and ADC: it does not work as expected

Tags: dc-motor, current-measurement, h-bridge, motor-controller

I'm trying to replicate a motor stall detector I found on a PCB of a commercial device (chinese). This is the schematic:
[image]

I'm using an ESP8266, resistors with same value as in schematic, two MMBT3906 as PNP and two MMBT3904 as NPN. Analyzing schematic when motor is running the `Vadc` is near to `VCC/2` and when the stall occours `Vadc` should drop due to the motor stall which is like a short-circuit.

But when I try it, the voltage does not change when the motor stall.

What I'm doing wrong?

---

PS: I cannot find the transistors used in the original device, and their codes are very hard to read. These are two photos of them I take with digital microscope:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a WAG, so not posted  as and answer.  Try increasing the base resistors.  Maybe 10k.  You want the motor to turn, but you don't want the transistors in saturation.  10k may be too much for the motor to run reliably.  At any rate, you need to find a compromise between motor running and the transistors (not quite) saturated.

Comment: Why I should avoid saturation? In an H-Bridge they act as switches, didn't they?

Comment: Yeah, but in saturation there will be little to no variation in the voltage drop across the transistors.

Comment: Are you using the identical motor type and supply voltage? Your transistors appear to be significantly wimpier than the originals (200mA vs 800mA).

Comment: I don't know how accurate your ADC is or how much voltage loss you can accept, but an alternative is to place a small resistor in the +3V or GND line and measure the voltage across that.

Comment: where is your freewheel path

Comment: _" the voltage does not change when the motor stall."_ - what is the voltage across each transistor at stall?

Answer (score 0):

Your H bridge uses diagonal pairs to drive the motor in one direction. If the motor stalls only the coil resistance exists across the bridge and the current may rise ten times (10x). It is not a short circuit, nor is it a short to 3V or 0V because the switches are now simply low resistance current switches, that seem to be well matched.

The commutated current thru the motor inductance is 1% to 10% max of the start/stall current due to coil resistance.  The transistor switches need to be high gain to be low loss.

To pull the voltage down, you need to lower NPN impedance with a much smaller base resistance or choose NPN's with high hFE.

To get good saturation voltage Ic/Ib=10 so the base R should be 10x the motor coil resistance.

It still won't reduce the filtered voltage to zero but it will shift down by the ratio of Rs of the switch.  **Rs=Vce(sat)/Ic and varies inversely with current.**

Comment: To measure the coil resistance I can use a tester set on Ohm and simply measure on motor pin?

Answer (score 0):

If the operation of this circuit is based only on the difference between the nominal current and the stall current, then it is very fragile. For such a circuit to give a significant voltage shift of the midpoint of the measuring resistors when the motor stalls, the lower pair of transistors must differ in saturation current from the upper pair. Otherwise, even if the motor has zero winding resistance, the voltage across it will converge symmetrically to Vcc/2, and the voltage at the input of the ADC will not change.

But it is possible that the original principle of action is a little trickier and based on back-emf. When the motor is supposedly rotating, the microcontroller turns OFF all the transistors, except for one (for example, the lower right). If the motor actually rotates, then it generates back-emf, which is measured by the ADC. And if it does not rotate, then it does not generate, and ADC measures the zero. The interval between switching off the current and measuring the back-emf should be chosen enough for the inductive current decay.

Comment: I do not understand very well, if I turn ON 3 transistor at the same time a pair will be in short, so motor is not powered anymore right? To measure back-emf the motor has to spin due to inertia? In this case I cannot do this due to the motor rotate very slow and it is attached to a gearbox so if I remove power it stop immediately.

Comment: "Closed" here meant non-conducting.

Yes, during the back-emf measurement motor is not powered. If you measure back-emf 1 or 10 milliseconds after de-energizing, almost any motor will not have time to change the speed. Your "immediate" stop of a motor (let's say 100 milliseconds) means 1 million operations for a microcontroller. These are different time scales.